# Best solution contains entities rejected from move filter?

Tags: optaplanner

I've the following:

Fact "job":

```
public class Job {
    String name;
    long duration;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(long duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
}
```

Fact "Machine":

```
public class Machine {

    String name;
    long capacity;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    public void setCapacity(long capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }
}
```

Planning Entity:

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Assignment {
    Job job;
    Machine machine;

    @PlanningVariable(nullable = true, valueRangeProviderRefs = { "jobRange" })
    public Job getJob() {
        return job;
    }

    public void setJob(Job job) {
        this.job = job;
    }

    @PlanningVariable(nullable = true, valueRangeProviderRefs = { "machineRange" })
    public Machine getMachine() {
        return machine;
    }

    public void setMachine(Machine machine) {
        this.machine = machine;
    }

}
```

Solution:

```
public class Schedule implements Solution<BendableScore> {

    private BendableScore score;
    private ArrayList<Job> jobs;
    private ArrayList<Machine> machines;
    private ArrayList<Assignment> assignments = new ArrayList<>();

    private final long CAPACITY = 4;
    private final long DURATION = 1;
    private final int JOBS = 4;
    private final int MACHINES = 1;

    @Override
    public BendableScore getScore() {
        return this.score;
    }

    @Override
    public void setScore(BendableScore score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends Object> getProblemFacts() {

        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "jobRange")
    public ArrayList<Job> getJobs() {
        return jobs;
    }

    public void setJobs(ArrayList<Job> jobs) {
        this.jobs = jobs;
    }

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "machineRange")
    public ArrayList<Machine> getMachines() {
        return machines;
    }

    public void setMachines(ArrayList<Machine> machines) {
        this.machines = machines;
    }

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    public ArrayList<Assignment> getAssignments() {
        return assignments;
    }

    public void setAssignments(ArrayList<Assignment> assignments) {
        this.assignments = assignments;
    }
    private void addMachines() {
        machines = new ArrayList<Machine>();
        for (int i = 0; i < MACHINES; i++) {
            Machine m = new Machine();
            m.name = "Machine " + i;
            m.capacity = CAPACITY;
            machines.add(m);
        }

    }

    private void addOperations() {
        jobs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < JOBS; i++) {
            Job job = new Job();
            job.name = "Job " + i;
            job.duration = DURATION;
            jobs.add(job);
        }

    }

    private void addAssignments() {
        for (Job job : jobs) {
            for (Machine m : machines) {
                Assignment a = new Assignment();
                a.setJob(job);
                a.setMachine(m);
                assignments.add(a);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Schedule s = new Schedule();
        s.addMachines();
        s.addOperations();
        s.addAssignments();
        SolverFactory solverFactory = SolverFactory
                .createFromXmlResource("mauro/test2/domain/mauro.xml");
        final Solver solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                solver.solve(s);
            }
        });
        t.start();
        try {
            t.join(12000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (t.isAlive()) {
            solver.terminateEarly();
        }
        Schedule sol = (Schedule) solver.getBestSolution();
        for (Assignment a : sol.getAssignments()) {
            if (a.getMachine() == null) {
                System.out.println("Assignment without machine");
                continue;
            }
            if (a.getJob() == null) {
                System.out.println("Assignment without job");
                continue;
            }
            Machine m = a.getMachine();
            Job job = a.getJob();
            System.out.println("Job " + job.name + " on machine " + m.name );
        }
    }
}
```

Config xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver>

    <environmentMode>FULL_ASSERT</environmentMode>
    <solutionClass>mauro.test2.domain.Schedule</solutionClass>
    <entityClass>mauro.test2.domain.Assignment</entityClass>
    <!-- Score configuration -->
    <scoreDirectorFactory>
        <scoreDefinitionType>BENDABLE</scoreDefinitionType>
        <bendableHardLevelsSize>2</bendableHardLevelsSize>
        <bendableSoftLevelsSize>2</bendableSoftLevelsSize>
        <easyScoreCalculatorClass>mauro.test2.domain.ScheduleEasyScoreCalculator</easyScoreCalculatorClass>
    </scoreDirectorFactory>

    <!-- Optimization algorithms configuration -->
    <constructionHeuristic>
        <constructionHeuristicType>CHEAPEST_INSERTION</constructionHeuristicType>
    </constructionHeuristic>
    <localSearch>
        <termination>
            <secondsSpentLimit>10</secondsSpentLimit>
            <unimprovedStepCountLimit>500</unimprovedStepCountLimit>
        </termination>
        <unionMoveSelector>
            <changeMoveSelector>
                <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
                <selectionOrder>SHUFFLED</selectionOrder>
                <valueSelector>
                    <variableName>machine</variableName>
                </valueSelector>
                <entitySelector>
                    <filterClass>mauro.test2.domain.MachineChangeMoveFilter</filterClass>
                </entitySelector>
            </changeMoveSelector>
            <changeMoveSelector>
                <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
                <selectionOrder>SHUFFLED</selectionOrder>
                <valueSelector>
                    <variableName>job</variableName>
                </valueSelector>
                <entitySelector>
                    <filterClass>mauro.test2.domain.MachineChangeMoveFilter</filterClass>
                </entitySelector>
            </changeMoveSelector>
        </unionMoveSelector>
        <acceptor>
            <lateAcceptanceSize>400</lateAcceptanceSize>
            <entityTabuSize>7</entityTabuSize>
        </acceptor>
        <forager>
            <acceptedCountLimit>100</acceptedCountLimit>
        </forager>
    </localSearch>
</solver>
```

ScoreCalculator:

```
public class ScheduleEasyScoreCalculator implements
        EasyScoreCalculator<Schedule> {

    public Score<?> calculateScore(Schedule schedule) {
        int hardScore1 = 0;
        int softScore = 0;
        HashMap<Machine, Long> loads = new HashMap<Machine, Long>();
        for (Assignment a : schedule.getAssignments()) {
            Machine m = a.getMachine();
            Job job = a.getJob();
            if (m != null && job != null) {
                if (loads.containsKey(m)) {
                    loads.put(m, loads.get(m) + job.duration);
                } else {
                    loads.put(m, job.duration);
                }
                 softScore += job.duration;
            }
        }
        for (Machine m : loads.keySet()) {
            Long load = loads.get(m);
            if (load > m.capacity) {
                hardScore1 -= (load - m.capacity);
            }
        }
        HashMap<Job, Integer> jobAssignments = new HashMap<>();
        for (Assignment a : schedule.getAssignments()) {
            if (a.getJob() != null) {
                if (jobAssignments.containsKey(a.getJob())) {
                    jobAssignments.put(a.getJob(),
                            jobAssignments.get(a.getJob()) + 1);
                } else {
                    jobAssignments.put(a.getJob(), 1);
                }
            }
        }
        int hardScore2 = 0;
        for (Job job : jobAssignments.keySet()) {
            if (jobAssignments.get(job) > 1) {
                 hardScore2 -= jobAssignments.get(job);
            }
        }
        return BendableScore.valueOf(new int[] { hardScore1, hardScore2 },
                new int[] { 0, softScore });

    }
}
```

MoveFilter:

```
public class MachineChangeMoveFilter implements SelectionFilter<Assignment> {

    public boolean accept(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, ChangeMove selection) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Assignment selection) {
        if (selection.getMachine() != null && selection.getJob() != null
                && !selection.getJob().name.contains("1")) {
            System.out.println("assignment " + selection.getMachine().getName()
                    + " " + selection.getJob().getName() + " accepted");
            return true;
        }
        System.out.println("assignment " + selection.getMachine().getName()
                + " " + selection.getJob().getName() + " NOT accepted");
        return false;
    }

}
```

If I run the solver, I get assignments with "Job 1".
Of course i could remove "job 1" from problema facts, but in real case I would not accept assignments with certain shadow variable values.
What is wrong?
Thanks

Mauro

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange (probably a bug) that your entity class Assignment only has planning variables fields.

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Assignment {
    Job job; // @PlanningVariable - Probably should NOT be one
    Machine machine; // @PlanningVariable
}
```

Normally, there's always (at least) 1 field that uniquely defines the entity and 1 (or more) planning variables. See the optaplanner examples, such as MachineReassignment.

Comment: The class Assignment has two getters annoted as @PlanningVariable...
Did you loose some code?

Comment: No, I didn't. My point is: Why does the Job getter have @PlanningVariable annotation?

Comment: You're rigth, but I made an example in wich Assignment can have null Job and /or null Machine. I know that it would be better to have only Job as PlanningEntity with Machine as PlanningVariable.
By the way, I notice that if a solution in the construction phase chooses an assignment and that assignment is rejected from the search phase by the move selector, it still remains in the best solution. Is it correct? Does it means that the best solution is the one found in the construction phase?
In this case, is there a manner to avoid the construction phase choosing some entities with a selector?

Comment: Moreover, I've somthing else to ask: how can I find instructions on causes of score corruption (the score calculation is made with java objects, not drolls)?
I'm trying to update a customShadowVariable and use that in score calculation, but I have the score corruption exception.
What is the fact that causes score corruption?
I've tryied to inspect the code, but I can't figure why a score change in a move causes score corruption.
Could you help me?
Thanks a lot.